# Phonegap 3.3-3.4 How to add icon for IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, icons

I am building IOS on cloud. My local phonegap project only runs on android sdk, no ios sdk. Hence, I do not have the folder structure for ios.

Where should i place the app icon for ios ? I believe the default \www\res\icon path is not working. I have to manually place my android icon in \platforms\android\res\drawable for my android icon to work.

Answer (score 0):

i am using a hook for copying these files, because it seems that cordova is not able to do it.
http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/

Comment: may I check for the IOS icon "platforms/ios/YourAppName/...." . What should I use for YourAppName? Where is this value taken? As for phonegap 3.4, every project name is helloworld. I have set config.xml to my intended app name. When i use that app name, the build fails.

Comment: well, when you create your Project, you can set the name of your app:
   cordova create yourFolder com.example.MyApp yourAppName

or if you dont want do create a new one, you can use 'helloworld'

Comment: phonegap3.4 has the known bug. all project name is helloworld

Comment: hmm, im using cordova 3.5 and theres no problem. why dont you update?
Otherwise you have to use "platforms/ios/helloworld/.."

Comment: i shall try it... thanks.. Just saw phonegap released 3.5 too